# Dicom viewer y tags

Tags: c#, wpf

hice un pequeño visualizador de imágenes Dicom ,con wpf en c# , necesito ayuda para obtener los tags de esa imagen mostrada ,y mostrarlos en una nueva venta

Answer (score 1):

[DICOM Tag](https://rtmedical.com.br/dicom-tag/)
Cada imagen generada por un equipo médico tiene almacenada en su interior un bloque de información sobre los aspectos técnicos de la imagen, el paciente y los métodos de transferencia al principio, seguido de los datos reales de la imagen. Cada etiqueta [DICOM](https://rtmedical.com.br/o-que-e-dicom/) tiene tres componentes:
la etiqueta, la VR (Value Representation) y el nombre. La etiqueta es un identificador único de 16 bits que identifica la información descrita en la etiqueta. VR define el tipo de información que representa la etiqueta, como fecha, texto o número. El nombre es una descripción textual de la información descrita en la etiqueta.

Algunos ejemplos de etiquetas DICOM incluyen:

**(0010, 0010) Nombre del paciente:**
el nombre del paciente representado en la imagen o información médica
**(0010, 0020) Identificación del paciente:**
el número de identificación del paciente que se muestra en la imagen o información médica
**(0020, 000D) UID de instancia de estudio:**
un identificador único para cada estudio médico realizado